# Error while trying to copy file to many files using cp

Tags: linux, shell, unix, command-line, cp

Error when running this command, i think the command is clear to get the idea.

`cp file.txt /folder/*/*/*/file.txt`

Comment: read the [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/cp.1.html). `cp` does not have that feature.

Comment: `cp` can't do that. And this question should be on [unix.se].

Comment: You should include the text of the error message.  Also, you should include a description of what you are trying to accomplish.  "i think the command is clear" is not necessarily enough.

Answer (score 2):

You need a loop to do that:

```
for dir in /folder/*/*/*/; do cp file.txt "$dir"; done
```